# Find solution of a Polynomial Equation

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

If $4b^2+1/b^2=16$ then how do I find the solution of $b^4+4/b^4-63/b^2$?

From $4b^2+1/b^2=16$, I got $$(2b+1/b)^2 = 12 \tag{1}$$ and $$(2b-1/b)^2 = 20 \tag{2}.$$

By solving equation (1), $$2b+1/b = 2\sqrt{3}$$ and by solving equation (2), $$2b-1/b = 2\sqrt{5},$$
but I couldn't find a way to proceed further.

4 options are given below. From these 4, I have to choose one as answer.

a) -1/4

b) -2

c) 3

d) 1/4

[Edited]

Thank you all for the suggestions you made.  Now I have found the answer. The following is how I came across the solution.

Solution:

[image: solution]

Comment: You need to edit it again in Mathjax and check the numbers and variables in your post to make sure it is stated correctly.

Comment: You've made arithmetical errors in your question.

Comment: Thanks -@Wang YeFei and @Suzu Hirose

Comment: $b^2=t$. $4t+\frac{1}{t}=16$. $(4t-\frac{1}{t})^2=16\cdot 15$, $4t-\frac{1}{t}=\pm 4\sqrt{15}$. $t=2\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{15}$. Then one needs only to put into $x=t^2+\frac{4}{t^2}-\frac{63}{t}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's surely an elementary method that doesn't require solving for $b$, but here's a method that doesn't require much cleverness:

Denote $u := b^2$. Then, clearing denominators gives that the first equation is equivalent to $$f(u) := 4 u^2 - 16 u + 1,$$ and if we denote the quantity we're trying to evaluate by $A := b^4 - 63 b^{-2} + 4 b^{-4}$, then rewriting in terms of $u$, rearranging, and again clearing denominators gives that $$g(u) := u^4 - A u^2 - 63 u + 4 = 0 .$$

Since $u$ must be a root of both $f$ and $g$, the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) $\operatorname{Res}_u(f, g)$ of $f$ and $g$ must vanish, and that resultant is quadratic in $A$.

> Computing gives $\operatorname{Res}_u(f, g) = 16 A^2 + 8 A + 1 = (4 A + 1)^2$, so $A = -\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Thanks-@Travis Willse for your suggestion. Yes, I also think there should be another method to find the solution without solving 'b'. By substituting the value of 'b' in the given equation, I find it more complex to get it solved. The book from where I found the question suggests 4 options and from which I have to choose one. Sorry that I didn't write it in my question. After posting this comment I would edit my question to resolve any difficulties that may cause further.

Comment: Thanks@Travis Willse. Now I understood your explanation. I didn't study about computing the resultant of two polynomial equations. That's why I couldn't get your point. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

$$4b^2 + \frac{1}{b^2} -16 =0$$

$$4b^4 - 16b^2 + 1 = 0$$

$$let \;u = b^2$$

$$4u^2 - 16u + 1 = 0$$

$$u = \frac{4 \pm \sqrt{15}}{2}$$

$$b^2 = \frac{4 \pm \sqrt{15}}{2}$$

$$b = \sqrt{\frac{4 + \sqrt{15}}{2}}, \sqrt{\frac{4 - \sqrt{15}}{2}}, -\sqrt{\frac{4 + \sqrt{15}}{2}}, -\sqrt{\frac{4 - \sqrt{15}}{2}}$$

Then substitute into $b^4 + \frac{4}{b^4} - \frac{63}{b^2}$ as required.

Comment: Thanks @jack_cashman1 for your explanation.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. Now I got the answer.  I have attached the solution to my question.